# Install specific version of ng cli

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I'm using angular 2.4.9 for my application development so I need to use specific version of ng cli instead of the latest one.

I know the below command will install latest version of ng cli

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

But how can I install specific version of ng cli?

Answer (score 158, accepted):

This command would install the 1.0.0 version:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.0.0
```

You can see the available versions with the following command:

```
npm view @angular/cli
```

NB: You can also install the latest available version:

```
npm install @angular/cli@latest
```

Comment: Thank you. I did search for that however I was confused because of the '@' symbol in package name

Comment: You can use also dist-tags. i.e.: `npm install -g @angular/cli@v6-lts`

Answer (score 7):

npm install -g @angular/cli@{version-number}

Answer (score 4):

In case anyone stumbles on this question while looking for a way to use angular-cli to build Angular 2 apps, @angular/cli@1.0.0 generated apps installs angular 4.0.0 instead of 2xx.

To avoid the round-trip of uninstalling the cli and looking for the most recent version that builds 2xx, use @angular/cli@1.0.0-beta.33.1

It builds Angular 2.4.1 ;)

Comment: Precious! Thank you, @Nnanyielugo - huge help for someone who's picking up old Ng2 legacy code to bring him to life on Ng9!