# How to downgrade Angular CLI version?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm new in Angular 4 and I am getting this error,

```
Your global Angular CLI version (6.0.1) is greater than your local
version (1.4.1). The local Angular CLI version is used.
```

Can you please help me solving this ?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44759621/install-specific-version-of-ng-cli

Comment: Are you sure you need it? Global is used to start new projects meanwhile local is responsible for current project.

Answer (score 92):

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.1
```

Comment: You should explain why you're offering this solution - the consensus is to upgrade the local version to match the global version, and you're advising to do the exact opposite

Comment: Yes! For consistency! Angular CLI & config file has been changed a lot

Comment: I'm probably the only one that made this mistake but be sure to add the '@' symbol before anguilar/cli, silly oversight on my behalf.

Comment: now it should be ```npm cache verify```

Comment: I had to write:
npm cache clean --force

Answer (score 35):

**Quick fix :**

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm cache clean
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.1
```

---

**Explanation :**

If you want remove this warning, then you can downgrade your global `angular-cli` installation to eg. `1.4.1` by running above commands on terminal:

Complete Upgrade and Downgrade guide is on [GitHub README](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli).

Your project always uses CLI version on which you have created the project. You can see it in the warning while running `ng serve`.

If global version is greater than Local version then local version is used.

It is also defined in your `package.json` file.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
     ....
}
```

[image: CLI warning]

[Reference Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39826902/i-want-to-downgrade-angular-cli-globally-as-my-project-is-using-older-version-of?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: I felt like an up-vote wasn't enough.  Thank you @sangwin-gawande :)

Answer (score 9):

1) Do you have other projects which are using angular (and what version of CLI are they using)

2) Once you identify which version you want to retain, you can uninstall the current version by

global:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

or local

```
npm uninstall @angular/cli
```

3) Then install desired version in the same scope as you uninstalled (making sure of any dependencies with other components)

**global**

*specific version*

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@1.4.1
```

*latest version*

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

**local**
Same as global but without the "-g" flag

Ideally the versions should be latest unless you figure out any compatibility issues

**Edit**:

> *Angular CLI 6.xxx*

has a breaking change of "angular.json" in new vs ".angular.json" in old (difference of dot in file name). Use [Error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810580/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found) if moving to angular 6

Comment: after this i am getting this error: Local workspace file ('angular.json') could not be found.

Comment: i check by ng -version and ng -version --global then both version is now 6.0.1

Comment: Hi Mukesh, sorry for the trouble, but in latest angular cli 6, they had this as breaking change (although these are the generic commands for updating all modules

Comment: @MukeshPrajapati Follow this (more specific to current release) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49810580/error-local-workspace-file-angular-json-could-not-be-found

Answer (score 6):

Do the following to Downgrade/Upgrade

1. > npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
2. #Install npm-check-updates

   > $ npm i -g npm-check-updates
3. > npm cache clean --force

   If you get error do it manually as below:

   open run , enter %appdata%

   [image]
4. Specify which version you want to install

   > npm install -g @angular/cli@**x.x.x**

   This will get the latest cli version:

   > npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: My problem was different to the OP's problem, but I had to redo all the above steps without the -g parameter to get working.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same warning:

> Your global Angular CLI version (11.0.6) is greater than you local
> version (11.0.5).

So before unisntalling the old version or downgrading, I took the basic command:

```
ng update @angular/cli @angular/core
```

By updating these packages from the registry, the warning was gone and my current project was updated to the latest version.