# This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^15.0.0, but Angular version 17.2.4 was found instead

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular-cli, angular15

I tried an update from angular 10 to 15, after doing the ng update and running ng version

[image]

when i try ng serve i got the message This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^15.0.0,
but Angular version 17.2.4 was found instead.

i tried :
npm uninstall -g angular-cli@17 --force
then clear cache then  npm i @angular/cli@15.2.10 --allow-dirty --force

Still got the same error , can you please help on how i completely uninstalll Angular 17, because i am forced to work with Angular 15, thanks

Comment: What do you have in your package.json file? Especially what's version of angular core and angular cli ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to downgrade Angular CLI version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363530/how-to-downgrade-angular-cli-version)